# Conversion formula for RGB to RCCB

Tags: image, image-processing, type-conversion, rgb

Can anybody tell me the conversion Formula for converting RGB Format to RCCB?
I have tried to search it on Internet but couldnt find anything.

Thanks!

Manish

Comment: It depends on which RGB and which RCCB are you discussing. Just to be sure, you are speaking something like RYYB in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_filter_array#List_of_color_filter_arrays ? (this one? http://www.imatest.com/docs/raw/). In fact RYYB is a good approximation, if you do not know the response function (which in any case should be similar to Y)

Comment: Thanks for your Response. After your Suggestion I tried to look for RYYB and there is also not much Information About it. If it is possible could you please guide me to the rigt direction. Manish

Comment: You will see in the second link, a link about RCCC, so you can see how to get R <-> RCCC. You may generalize with B.  How to get Y from RGB is also a easy task.  Then it is your job to implement. I have very little interest on RCCC/RCCB, so I cannot help further.